# Conversion from string "Insert into userinfo ('FirstName' to type 'Long' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to insert data into my database and when I clicked sign up button where I put my code, I will get a prompt that says:

> Conversion from string "Insert into userinfo ('FirstName' to type 'Long' is not valid.

How can I fix this?

```
Dim bytFlag As Byte
Dim intI As Integer
Dim strC As String
Dim ans As Integer = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure on your inputs?", "ANADIET MEAL PLANNER", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
   
    If Len(txtPW.Text) >= 8 Then
        For intI = 1 To Len(txtPW.Text)
            strC = Mid$(txtPW.Text, intI, 1)
            If strC >= "!" And strC <= "\" Then
                bytFlag = bytFlag Or &H8
            End If
            If strC >= "0" And strC <= "9" Then
                bytFlag = bytFlag Or &H4
            End If
            If strC >= ":" And strC <= "@" Then
                bytFlag = bytFlag Or &H8
            End If
            If strC >= "A" And strC <= "Z" Then
                bytFlag = bytFlag Or &H2
            End If
            If strC >= "a" And strC <= "z" Then
                bytFlag = bytFlag Or &H1
            End If
        Next intI
    End If
    If bytFlag <> &HF Then
        MessageBox.Show("Password must contain capital letters, small letters, numbers and special characters.", "ANADIET MEAL PLANNER", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    ElseIf txtAge.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill up all informations!", "ANADIET MEAL PLANNER", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    ElseIf txtFN.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill up all informations!", "ANADIET MEAL PLANNER", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    ElseIf txtLN.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill up all informations!", "ANADIET MEAL PLANNER", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    ElseIf txtPW.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill up all informations!", "ANADIET MEAL PLANNER", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    ElseIf txtRPW.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill up all informations!", "ANADIET MEAL PLANNER", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    ElseIf txtUN.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill up all informations!", "ANADIET MEAL PLANNER", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    ElseIf radioValue1.Checked = False And radioValue2.Checked = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill up all informations!", "ANADIET MEAL PLANNER", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    ElseIf txtPW.Text <> txtRPW.Text Then
        MessageBox.Show("Password do not match", "ANADIET MEAL PLANNER", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

    Else

        Dim n As Integer = txtAge.Text
        Dim s As String = n.ToString

        Try
            If ans = vbYes Then
                con.Open()
                cmd = New SqlCommand("Insert into userinfo ('FirstName', 'MiddleName', 'LastName', 'Age', 'Gender', 'Birthdate') values('" & txtFN.Text & "', '" & txtMN.Text & "', '" & txtAge.Text & "', '" & radioValue1.Text Or radioValue2.Text & "', '" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "')", con)
                con.Close()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical)
        End Try
```

Comment: Looks like you open a connection but don't execute the command. That aside, take your field names out of quotes.

Comment: You obviously haven't debugged your code. You need to do that before paying here. If you don't know how to use breakpoints, etc, then learn now.

Comment: Please see http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: Update: I just added the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() still not fixed a thing. I am just new with this pl.

Comment: If you changed your code then change your question. We shouldn't need to read comments to understand the question and also shouldn't need to guess where the exception is being thrown. DEBUGF YOUR CODE and provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Comment: If you want to check whether a `String` contains only letters, numbers and some other specific character then you need on line of code: `If Char.All(Function(ch) Char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch) OrElse "!@#$".Contains(ch)) Then`. That's the most succinct option and you could be excused for not knowing that but there are other options in between that are far simpler than what you have. Obviously you can use a different set of special characters. If the set is large then you can use a range, e.g. `Convert.ToInt32(ch) >= Convert.ToInt32(":"c) AndAlso Convert.ToInt32(ch) <= Convert.ToInt32("@"c)`.

Answer (score 0):

The first message box (the "are you sure?") is just annoying and insulting to the user. When you do use a message box use `DialogResult` as the return value rather than magic numbers. It will make your code easier to read.

Your life will be easier if you stop using the old VB6 methods and learn to use the .net methods. (This will be especially true when you need to use C#) `Len()` should be replaced with `.Length`. `Mid` should be `Substring`

Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

As much as possible methods should only do a single job. I have separated the data access code from the validation code.

In the validation code, I got rid of the byte flag stuff and used more readable .net methods. I think it will make the code easier to debug.

What is this code doing?

```
 Dim n As Integer = txtAge.Text
 Dim s As String = n.ToString
```

In the first place a `Text` property is a `String` and cannot be assigned to an `Integer` variable. You never seem to use either `n` or `s`.

Database objects like connections and commands should always be declared in the method where they are used so they can be properly disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks handle the declaration and disposing for you even if there is and error.

Identifier delimiters in Sql Server are `[ ]`. I am not sure what you are intending with single quotes surrounding your field name. I can't believe all your field names actually contain single quotes.

**Never** concatenate strings to build an sql command. **Always** use parameters to avoid sql injection and other reasons.

You have failed to provide a value for the last name. I made a guess that you have a text box called `txtLN`.

Datatypes are used in databases for a reason. Be sure to choose the appropriate type for the kind of data you are storing.

It is a bad idea to store Age in a database. In the first place it is redundant since it can always be calculated from the birth date. Secondly it could be incorrect as soon as tomorrow if the individual's birth date is tomorrow. If you were storing a value like Age, store it as an `Int`, not a `VarChar`. You probably need to delete this field in the database.

Date data should be stored as a `Date` type in the database. This will save you time recreating a date when you need it in code. Dates can be sorted and manipulated to determine age. Strings cannot. Again, correct your database.

What do you think this is going to do?

```
radioValue1.Text Or radioValue2.Tex
```

That makes no sense for providing a value for Gender.

In the parameters code, I had to guess at the datatype and field size for the name, gender and password fields. Check your database to get the correct values. As I mentioned before, delete the Age field and change the datetype of the `Birthdate` field to `Date`.

A final problem is that you never execute you command so nothing happens to the database.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Private Sub OPCode()
    If ValidateInput() Then
        Dim gender As String
        If radioValue1.Checked Then
            gender = "Male"
        Else
            gender = "Female"
        End If
        Try
            Dim strSql = "Insert into userinfo (FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Gender,Birthdate) values(@FName,@MName,@LName,@Gender,@BDate);"
            Using con As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
                    cmd As New SqlCommand(strSql, con)
                With cmd.Parameters
                    .Add("@FName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = txtFN.Text
                    .Add("@MName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = txtMN.Text
                    .Add("@LName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = txtLN.Text
                    .Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = gender
                    .Add("2BDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
                End With
                con.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub

Private Function ValidateInput() As Boolean
    Dim s = txtPW.Text
    Dim Number, Capital, Small, Special As Boolean
    If s.Length <= 8 Then
        For Each c As Char In s
            If Char.IsNumber(c) Then
                Number = True
                Continue For
            End If
            If Char.IsLower(c) Then
                Small = True
                Continue For
            End If
            If Char.IsUpper(c) Then
                Capital = True
                Continue For
            End If
            If Char.IsSymbol(c) OrElse Char.IsPunctuation(c) Then
                Special = True
            End If
        Next
    End If

    If Number AndAlso Small AndAlso Capital AndAlso Special Then
        MessageBox.Show("Password must contain capital letters, small letters, numbers and special characters.", "ANADIET MEAL PLANNER", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        Return False
    ElseIf txtFN.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill up all informations!", "ANADIET MEAL PLANNER", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Return False
    ElseIf txtLN.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill up all informations!", "ANADIET MEAL PLANNER", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Return False
    ElseIf txtPW.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill up all informations!", "ANADIET MEAL PLANNER", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Return False
    ElseIf txtRPW.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill up all informations!", "ANADIET MEAL PLANNER", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Return False
    ElseIf txtUN.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill up all informations!", "ANADIET MEAL PLANNER", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Return False
    ElseIf radioValue1.Checked = False And radioValue2.Checked = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill up all informations!", "ANADIET MEAL PLANNER", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Return False
    ElseIf txtPW.Text <> txtRPW.Text Then
        MessageBox.Show("Password do not match", "ANADIET MEAL PLANNER", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Return False
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

Of course, in a real application you would **NEVER** store passwords as plain text. The need to salted and encrypted.